# Apache htaccess cache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, xampp, windows-10

Using XAMPP and Windows 10 I'm experimenting with some htaccess rules.

I have a folder `C:\xampp\htdocs\website` and in this directory there is a .htaccess file, the full contents are;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

To test the .htaccess was working I added the following redirect rule to the end;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com
```

This successfully redirected my whole domain, great.

I have since deleted this line from my htaccess file, however my domain is **still** being redirected.

I have restarted Apache numerous times, cleared my browser history, cache and tried different browsers. I have also tried viewing the site in incognito mode.

Eventually the site returns to normal, this is after numerous service restarts and history deletions.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a more efficient way of testing the .htaccess?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to restart APache. Simple make the change in the htaccess file, clear your history/cache and hard reload the page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

You can also close and re-open the browser, see if that helps.